# How to upload .docx .xls .xlsx documents using AngularJS and Rails Paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am successfully uploading images, .pdf and .doc files but when I try to upload .docx, .xls and .xlsx types it fails with this error message in console:

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError (No handler found for "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64...
```

I added mime-types in config/initializers/mime-types.rb but that didn't help too.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes, but I forgot to write an answer. Will do it right now.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the Paperclip to the newest version.

New version of Paperclip doesn't support whole base64 string for some mime types, so I split first part of string where it tells what mime type is (e.g. "base64/application-pdf..."), then decode base64, assign content_type and file_name attributes and pass it to Paperclip. It works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for providing your answer. Would you be able to give a code sample?